# Cannot access the data in cookies with C# & .NET 7.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, razor-pages, .net-7.0

I'm trying to develop an app with Razor pages. For this reason, although I can view the product IDs and quantities that I added to the cart on my homepage and placed in cookies in the `Application/Cookies` tab of the developer tools on my `/Cart` page, I cannot access them with C# code. I give the image of the cookies for the homepage and `/Cart` page in the picture.

[image]

**Note:** `app.UseCookiePolicy();` in `Program.cs` is available.

Script where I create cookies:

```
function addToCart(productId) {
    var cart = getCart();
    var existingProduct = cart.find(item => item.productId === productId);
    if (existingProduct) {
        existingProduct.count += 1;
    } else {
        cart.push({ productId: productId, count: 1 });
    }
    setCart(cart);
    alert('Ürün sepete eklendi!');
}

function getCart() {
    var cart = getCookie('cart');
    if (!cart) {
        cart = [];
    } else {
        try {
            cart = JSON.parse(cart);
        } catch (error) {
            cart = [];
        }
    }
    return cart;
}

function setCart(cart) {
    setCookie('cart', JSON.stringify(cart), 7);
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var value = "; " + document.cookie;
    var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
    if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(";")[0];
}

function setCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    var newCookie = name + "=" + (value || "") + expires + "; path=/";
    console.log(newCookie);
    document.cookie = newCookie;
}
```

C# code I am trying to access the cookies:

```
public List<CartItem> CartItems { get; set; }

public void OnGet()
{
    CartItems = GetCartItems();
}

private List<CartItem> GetCartItems()
{
    var cartCookie = Request.Cookies["cart"];
    Console.WriteLine($"cartCookie: {cartCookie}");

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cartCookie))
    {
        try
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CartItem>>(cartCookie);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error parsing cart cookie: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    return new List<CartItem>();
}
```

Here `Console.WriteLine($"cartCookie: {cartCookie}");` I get an empty output as `cartCookie:`  for the line.

What I want to do is to transfer the products added to the cart with cookies for a simple e-commerce website where user login is not required. However, I cannot access cookies on the C# side while doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get cookie from Headers, try :

```
//var Cookie1 = Request.Headers.Cookie;//get the cookie
var Cookie = Request.Headers.Cookie.ToString();
var cartCookie = Cookie.Split('=').Last(); //get cartCookie value
```

result:

[image]

Comment: I can't believe I spent so much time on a simple problem, thank you. So, why is there a use of `Request.Cookies` in all documentation?

Comment: Hi @muazfurkan, you are welcome:)  ,we can use `Request.Cookies` to get the collection of Cookies (format like: KeyValuePair<string,string>) for this request. format like : `document.cookie = "user=John";`. If we use `var newCookie = name + "=" + (value || "") + expires + "; path=/";` , it cannot be accessed by `Request.Cookies`. But we can get from heasers.